# Format decimal to currency, should be in cents for values $0 to $1

Tags: .net, formatting, decimal, currency

I have a decimal variable which represents a donation amount. Currently I am displaying it on screen as a currency like so-

```
DonationAmount.ToString("C");
```

This gives the following output (given a US locale)

```
1 -> $1.00
2 -> $2.00
0.5 -> $0.50
```

I am happy with the first two example, but want to have "0.5" show as "50c".

My current solution is with a conditional-

```
if (DonationAmount > 1)
   return (DonationAmount * 100m).ToString() + "c";
else
   return DonationAmount.ToString("C");
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide your own Custom Formatter (say "cents") that will format the string as "50c".

Implementing your own `IFormatProvider` is not that difficult. Once you've done that, you would then pass it as a parameter when calling `String.Format()` or `ToString()`.

Examples of this can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx or here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/custstrformat.aspx.

```
public class StringFormatInfo : IFormatProvider, ICustomFormatter
{
   ...
}

return number.ToString("{0:cents}", new StringFormatInfo());
```